# Uso Multiselect bootstrap "No muestra los acentos"

Tags: sql, asp.net, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

No se que tengo que confirmar para que me muestre con acento lo que pongo en el nonSelectedText

```
onInitialized: function($select, $container) {

            },
            enableHTML: false,
            buttonClass: 'btn btn-default',
            inheritClass: false,
            buttonWidth: 'auto',
            buttonContainer: '<div class="btn-group" />',
            dropRight: false,
            dropUp: false,
            selectedClass: 'active',
            // Maximum height of the dropdown menu.
            // If maximum height is exceeded a scrollbar will be displayed.
            maxHeight: false,
            checkboxName: false,
            includeSelectAllOption: false,
            includeSelectAllIfMoreThan: 0,
            selectAllText: ' Seleccionar todo',
            selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
            selectAllName: false,
            selectAllNumber: true,
            selectAllJustVisible: true,
            enableFiltering: false,
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: false,
            enableFullValueFiltering: false,
            enableClickableOptGroups: false,
            enableCollapsibelOptGroups: false,
            filterPlaceholder: 'Buscar',
            // possible options: 'text', 'value', 'both'
            filterBehavior: 'text',
            includeFilterClearBtn: true,
            preventInputChangeEvent: false,
            nonSelectedText: 'elija una opción',
            nSelectedText: 'selected',
            allSelectedText: 'All selected',
            numberDisplayed: 3,
            disableIfEmpty: false,
            disabledText: '',
            delimiterText: ', ',
            templates: {
                button: '<button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="multiselect-selected-text"></span> <b class="caret"></b></button>',
                ul: '<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu"></ul>',
                filter: '<li class="multiselect-item filter"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span><input class="form-control multiselect-search" type="text"></div></li>',
                filterClearBtn: '<span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default multiselect-clear-filter" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i></button></span>',
                li: '<li><a tabindex="0"><label></label></a></li>',
                divider: '<li class="multiselect-item divider"></li>',
                liGroup: '<li class="multiselect-item multiselect-group"><label></label></li>'
            }
        },
```

Aqui muestro una imagen de como me muestra las letras con acentos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa la codificación debe estar en `UTF-8`

Comment: Si esta en UTF-8   <meta charset="utf-8">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que estés hablando de [Bootstrap Multiselect de David Stutz](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect), si te fijás en su GitHub podés ver que hay varias menciones de problemas o mejoras sugeridas en lo referido a acentos, internacionalización, etc.(por citar uno:
[Problema en búsqueda con caracteres UTF-8](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/976)). Todo eso hace suponer que actualmente no tiene un soporte (o al menos no uno bueno) para caracteres acentuados. Por suerte, el español es un idioma amplio por lo que seguramente podrás encontrar algún sinónimo a las palabras acentuadas que tratabas de poner.

Saludos!,